# Spring: Generic injection not working

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

In my project I have following structure of repositories:

```java
public interface IRepository<T> { ... }

public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> implements IRepository<T> { ... }

@Repository
public class ARepository extends AbstractRepository<A>
    implements IRepository<A> { ... }  // added line 


@Repository
public class BRepository extends AbstractRepository<B>
    implements IRepository<B> { ... }  // added line 


@Repository
public class CRepository extends AbstractRepository<C>
    implements IRepository<C> { ... }  // added line
```

Now I would like to inject them into proper services as follows:

```java
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowire
    IRepository<A> arepository;

    ...
}
```

It compiles fine, but when Spring context is starting I'm getting following error `No qualifying bean of type 'some.package.IRepository<?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: aRepository, bRepository, cRepository`.

As far as I'm aware, injection in Spring 4 (4.3.13.RELEASE used in my project) should handle this situation well by using generic types as a form of qualifier. Unfortunately it's not working for me. Should I change some configurations as well? I have searched a bit on that topic but didn't found anything useful. I have ended using names for my beans and `@Qualifier` annotation but with that solution I'm still dependant on implementation.

Did anyone have similar problems and managed to solve them?

@Edit
Not mentioned before but as one comment suggests that it may have something to do with this, I have to write that this projects uses aspects(CTW) and is built by `ajc` compiler.

Comment: Give a name for the bean

Comment: Tip: Rather autowire your stuff in a constructor. That way you can mockito test MyService. Useful for your unit tests.

Comment: How do you initialise the beans? Could you post the code?

Comment: There is no constructor defined in neither abstract class nor implementations. The beans are initialized by Spring thanks to `@Repository` annotation. Gonna update a post with them.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the following code:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
}

public abstract class MyAbstract<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
}

@Service
public class MyServiceInteger extends MyAbstract<Integer> implements MyInterface<Integer> {
}

@Service
public class MyServiceString extends MyAbstract<String> implements MyInterface<String> {
}

//in a service
@Inject
private MyInterface<String> stringSomething;
```

And it works just fine. I did get an error message like yours at one point, but that was due to using the same generic parameter (String) in both services. Are you 100% sure that you are using (only) Spring 4.x? Check your classpath..

Comment: First, Spring official blog says that it should work: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics. Second I wrote that I'm aware of `@Qualifier` approach and use it already but I don't like it.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Checked libs in war but all spring components are in version `4.3.13.RELEASE`. I will try to change `@Repository` for `@Component` although I don't have much hope in that.

Comment: I tried @Repository as well, same result.. Also tried with two classes being sub/superclass in the generic parameter, also worked..

Comment: Maybe some special compiler flag or something makes it not retain the pieces of generics that survive compilation, and Spring use for this?

Comment: As I'm thinking now, we use `ajc` here. So I guess this may be doing job here.